# Comments that support MathJax for GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, mathjax, disqus, jekyll-extensions

> > I'm looking for a comments module like Disqus (sadly, this one doesn't support MathJax) that support MathJax in GitHub pages. Any recommendation?